# How to get inverse object relation when specified related_name

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following model similiar to the relationship in the django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/:

```
class Employee(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)  
    company = models.ForeignKey('companies.Company', related_name='company', blank=True, null=True)
    brand = models.OneToOneField('companies.Brand', related_name='brand', blank=True, null=True)
```

I try to get the employee from the Brand like this:

```
attendees = Brand.objects.filter(pk=2)

for a in attendees:
    print a.employee
```

I get the error:

> 'Brand' object has no attribute 'employee'

I have also tried:

```
attendees = Brand.objects.filter(pk=2)

for a in attendees:
    print a.employee_set
```

and get:

> 'Brand' object has no attribute 'employee_set'

How can I get the `employee` from the `brand`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related name:

```
brand = models.OneToOneField('companies.Brand', related_name='brand')
```

I changed it to:

```
brand = models.OneToOneField('companies.Brand', related_name='employee')
```